# Save a form using localstorage onsubmit

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm new to the whole localstorage thing but all the other tutorials and stack overflow pages i've followed have gotten me nowhere. I'm trying to save user details into localstorage and see them through the console. The submitting is fine and it calls the function perfectly but whenever i look at the console it either shows nothing, errors or "null".

```js
 function onSubmitForm(){
           localStorage.clear();
           /*What i think this does is set the value to whatever the user 
has submitted in the form and then call it to the console for me to see*/
           var input = document.getElementById("firstname");
           localStorage.setItem("firstname", input.value); 
           var storedValue = localStorage.getItem("firstname"); 
           
           /*another failed attempt, i do not have these both running at the same time*/
           console.log(localStorage.getItem("firstname"));
           console.log(localStorage.getItem("lastname"));
           console.log(localStorage.getItem("email"));
           console.log(localStorage.getItem("enquiry"));
           
/*This is the clear the form of all text*/
        var form = document.getElementById("contactForm");
        form.reset();
        alert("Your enquiry has gone through");
    }
```

```html
<!--I hope to get these all to store but just the first name will be enough for me right now-->

<form action="" name="contactForm" id="contactForm" onSubmit="onSubmitForm()">

    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="John"/>

    <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Doe"/>

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="john@doe.com"/>

    <label for="enquiry">Enquiry</label>
    <input type="text" name="enquiry" id="enquiry" placeholder="Your enquiry here:"/>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

  </form>
```

Comment: Your example code works for me in Chrome.

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/x61p3ya9/ (note that in a jsfiddle I had to change the JS load -type setting to "no wrap in <head>" to emulate how it works on an actual webpage)

Comment: Really? It doesn't show me anything in the console when i run it.

Comment: You guys were right, it does work. I was looking at the wrong part of the console, i done goofed.